# Java: Запись массива в HashMap

Tags: java, массивы, java-hashmap

Есть `HashMap<String, boolean[]> map` при простой записи

```
map.put("v",{true, false, true, true});
```

IDE выдает ошибку, что нельзя делать так 
Но, если же я до этого создам отдельный массив

```
boolean[] bool = {true, false, true, true}
```

И потом заброшу bool то все работает 
Однако, таких последовательностей многовато, и не совсем удобно (даже для памяти) создавать каждый раз новую переменную массив 
Каким образом можно сделать это попроще?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
map.put("v", new boolean[] {true, false, true});
```